# Adding ssd hdd to asus n73sv

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

ASUS N73SV has 2 HDD (750GB each). I would like to replace one of them with an SSD. It will look like :

- 1 HDD 750 GB
- 1 SSD (size doesn't matter).

How do the computer will treat them, will treat as 750 GB + ssd's size?  Or will be 2 different hdds?  And will I be able to install the system on ssd, and the D:/ will be the first hdd (750 gb)?

Comment: are you existing HDDS part of a RAID?

Comment: no, it doesn't support raid hdds. that's written in the description of the product.

Comment: There is your answer: they will be treated as separate volumes.

Answer (score 1):

Since the HDDs are not part of a RAID/JBOD array, replacing the hard disk will result in it being shown as 2 separate drives.

And yes, you will be able to install the SSD. Not sure which will be the first device though.